# How can I reduce the sound of water moving through a pipe?

Tags: insulation, acoustic

### Introduction

I am re-purposing a room from a kitchen to bedroom. The room has a concrete-block built wall through which cast iron water pipes pass.

Here is the approximate schematic

```
neighbor | p | my room
```

`|  |` is a single concrete block, and the `p` is the pipe located inside it.

Whenever the neighbor uses the kitchen pipe, there is a hissing noise in the pipes. Closing the pipe produces a distinct "thud" sound.

I was considering:

1. demolishing a part of the wall (one side of a single block) to allow better inspection
2. acoustically insulating the pipe with some wrapping material
3. green gluing the entire wall

The problem with step 3 is that I don't have much space for the additional layer on top of green glue because I have windows to go up to the wall, leaving very little space on the window frame. 2 cm would perhaps be possible.

Even if the window would not present a problem, I would also not like to lose too much space of the room.

```
============ <- wall with pipes
w <- window
w 
w
```

The wall concrete blocks are covered with 10-sand:4-lime:1-cement mixture (type K mortar equivalent), looking something like this:

[image]

I might be able to get additional space for green glue by ripping that layer off.

I have a good neighbor and it might be cheaper to arrange changing the pipes. However, demolishing his kitchen tiles to get to the installations is most likely out of the question.

### Question

1. How can I acoustically insulate the cast iron pipe with some kind of wrapping material?
2. How can I acoustically insulate the room wall through which the pipes pass efficiently with just an inch or inch and a half to spare?

Comment: You could install a surge arrester in the basement.  It could help with the banging (water hammer)

Comment: @ChrisCudmore I live in a residential building. Can I install something like that on the part of the pipe I have access to?

Comment: Yes, but you'll need landlord / condo board approval.

Answer (score 1):

Acoustic paint - http://www.acousticalsurfaces.com/coat-of-silence/coat-of-silence.html

You will lose very little room and it doesn't take much time.  Read reviews and instructions to make sure which type is best for your walls.

There is also acoustical sheetrock quietrock?  You could strip the wall with 2x4s and put sheetrock over.